# logstash forwareder doesn't release file handle

Tags: filehandle, logstash-forwarder

I am running logstash forwareder to ship logs.
Forwarder,logstash,elasticsearch all are on localhost.
I have one UI application whose log files is read by shipper. When forwarder is running, archiving of log file doesn't work. logs are appended in same file. I have configured log file to archive every minute, so I can see the change. As soon as I stop forwarder, log file archiving starts working.
I guess forwarder keep holding file handle that's why file does not get archived.
Please help me on this.

regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Running on windows? There exists known unfixed bugs.
See https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/1944
for some kind of work around.